# Lazy loading a web component

Tags: web-component

We have a huge web component (2MB) that is currently loading in the `<head>` element but this dramatically reduces our page load time.

I was thinking if we can somehow lazy load our web component?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your web component is contained in an HTML import, currently stored in the `<head>`, you could lazyload that imported file whenever you'd like with javascript:

```
var import = document.createElement('link');
import.rel = 'import';
import.href = 'path/to/your/import.html';
document.head.appendChild(import);
```

Alternatively, you could try just moving your HTML import out of the head and into the body (near the bottom), which may reduce load time because it would no longer block parsing of the body.

Comment: Let's say the custom element already exists in the html but the link[import] isn't yet inserted into the HTML. What will happen when the link[import] is loaded? Will the element get initialized and show up properly? Why in all examples link[import] is in the `<head>` instead of the end of the HTML like the other js scripts?

Comment: Per http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#unresolvedels => "Because custom elements are registered by script using document.registerElement(), they can be declared or created before their definition is registered by the browser"

Comment: basically, if you are using them on the body, the element will be ignored until your import is reached, causing the component to "appear"? aka be painted when link tag is reached?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jake Archibald's great article about ECMA Script modules in browsers. He elaborates on loading strategies and reveals some best practices. The article is found here: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

An elaborated deep-dive article on JS modules is found here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

I hope this'll help you find a way of lazy loading Web Components in your application.